# How do I add attachments in iPad Mail?

Tags: mail.app, ipad

My friend has an iPad 2 and we can't seem to find a way to attach photos to emails using the standard Mail software the device comes with.

What are we missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything - the design of the app is to sandbox it - see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25678/downloading-and-uploading-files-through-safari-ios/25690#25690 for details on the sandbox

Comment: The 3 answers already provided answer your question - you have to do things in a different way - Mail cannot grab files from other apps, but other apps can pass files to mail.  This happens in many other programs.  The currently active program is the only one allowed to pass such files/data to another program, so you can send a pic to mail to include it as an attachment,, or oven a PDF in Dropbox and send to to iBooks to read etc etc, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work this way.

You can add images by

- going to the **Photos** app,
- selecting the pictures you want to add
  (I believe it's a button on the upper right of the screen to switch to selection mode),
- and tap on `Copy`, once you selected them,
- then you can go back to your mail, tap where you want to add them
- and select `Paste`

Answer (score 3):

That's right (and sometimes rather confusing). To add pictures to a message, you start in the Photo app and select pictures to share. You can then either send the pictures directly from Photos or copy them to the clipboard and paste them into your emai afterwards.